# Function to multiple every matrix by every vector?

Tags: r, function, loops, apply

I am implementing a technique whereby I take two matrices (M1 and M2) and multiply them each by the same "skewer" vector (B), producing results vectors R1 and R2, then taking a correlation of these vectors, as so:

```
P1 <- data.frame(split(rnorm(5*16, 1, 1), 1:16))
M1 <- matrix(unlist(P1[1,]), nrow = 4)
M1[upper.tri(M1)] <- t(M1)[upper.tri(M1)]

P2 <- data.frame(split(rnorm(5*16, 1, 1), 1:16))
M2 <- matrix(unlist(P2[1,]), nrow = 4)
M2[upper.tri(M2)] <- t(M2)[upper.tri(M2)]

B <- rnorm(4, 0, 1)

R1 <- M1 %*% B
R2 <- M2 %*% B
cor(R1, R2)
```

However, I need to extend this in two ways: *i*) I need to do this for *n* (4000, but showing here for 2) vectors of B, which I have achieved using a function as below, and *ii*) **performing this for each iteration of a posterior distribution of the matrices** (1000, using 5 here in the example), which I have achieved using a for loop inside the function. This returns a data frame with one row per iteration, and 1 column per skewer, and each cell giving the correlation of response vectors. While this works, the for loop is slow -

```
com_rsk_p2 <- function(m1, m2, n = 2){
  nitt <- length(m1[,1])
  k <- sqrt(length(m1))
  B <- split(rnorm(n*k, 0, 1), 1:n)

  rv_cor <- split(rep(NA, times = n*nitt), 1:nitt)

  for(i in 1:nitt){
    R1 <- sapply(B, function(x) x %*% matrix(unlist(m1[i,]), ncol = k))
    R2 <- sapply(B, function(x) x %*% matrix(unlist(m2[i,]), ncol = k))

    rv_cor[[i]] <- diag(matrix(mapply(cor, list(R1), list(R2)), ncol = n))
  }

  return(t(data.frame(rv_cor)))
}
```

I've been working on this for a couple of days, but coming up short - is it possible **to use a non-looping/apply approach so that each iteration of M1 and M2 are multiplied by each skewer, storing the result vector correlations for each case?** I'm sure there must be some trick that I am missing!

```
> out <- com_rsk_p2(P1, P2) 
> out
         [,1]       [,2]
X1  0.7622732  0.8156658
X2  0.4414054  0.4266134
X3  0.4388098 -0.1248999
X4  0.5438046  0.7723585
X5 -0.5833943 -0.5294521
```

Ideally I'd like to have the objects `R1` and `R2` remain within the function because I will use these for some other things later on  when I add to this function (calculating angles between vectors etc.).

---

*Updated 26/04/2018* I have created a list of the matrices, and matrix of the B vectors, and I can multiply a single matrix by each vector of B as below - the key I am looking for is to extend this to an efficient approach that multiplies each matrix in the list by each vector of B:

```
P1 <- data.frame(split(round(rnorm(5*16, 1, 1),2), 1:16))
P2 <- data.frame(split(round(rnorm(5*16, 1, 1),2), 1:16))

nitt <- length(P1[,1])
k <- sqrt(length(P1))

M1L <- list(rep(NA, times = nitt))
M2L <- list(rep(NA, times = nitt))

for(i in 1:nitt){
    M <- matrix(P1[i,], byrow = T, ncol = k)
    M[lower.tri(M)] <- t(M)[lower.tri(M)]
    M1L[[i]] <- M
    M <- matrix(P2[i,], byrow = T, ncol = k)
    M[lower.tri(M)] <- t(M)[lower.tri(M)]
    M2L[[i]] <- M
}

B <- matrix(round(rnorm(2*4, 0, 1),2), ncol = 2)
matrix(unlist(M2L[[1]]), ncol = 4) %*% B

> matrix(unlist(M2L[[1]]), ncol = 4) %*% B
        [,1]    [,2]
[1,]  0.1620 -0.3203
[2,]  0.6027  0.8148
[3,]  0.9763 -1.3177
[4,] -0.5369  0.5605
```

Comment: I imagine the solution will involve the matrices into a list, as so: `p1 <- diag(2); p2 <- diag(2)*2; p <- list(p1, p2); B <- c(0.5, 0.2); lapply(p, function(x) x %*% B) 
`

Comment: `apply` still uses loops, you're just not writing the loops explicitly anymore. The only way you'll get big speedups is if you can rework the problem to be more vectorized/have fewer operations. (I can't think of a good way).

Comment: One note, you can't transpose data frames because Columns are Special. As soon as you run `t()` on a data frame, it will be converted to a matrix. So `t(data.frame(rv_cor))` is a really inefficient way to do `t(rv_cor)`. If you want a data frame result, do `data.frame(t(rv_cor))`. (And I'd recommend making `rv_cor` matrix not a list, maybe that's why you have the `data.frame()` first).

Comment: noted on apply - a vectorised approach is what I mean to be looking for! thanks!

Comment: Do you know all the B values in advance? It would probably be good to add multiple B values into your question since that's a big part of it.

Comment: B is generated using random numbers in the function - in the example script is a list contain two (or *n*) sublists, the sublists are vectors of 4 (or *k*) numerical values